# OpenCL 16-bit floats

Tags: c, opencl

How to pass 16-bit floats (cl halfs) to an OpenCL kernel in .cl file?
I have in my .cl file:

```
__kernel void func(__global half* a, __global half* b, __global half* res){
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    res[i] = a[i] - b[i];
}
```

I want to pass a and b in C file and treat them as floating point values.
I tried using cl_half, but it's an unsigned short, so something like:

```
cl_half aData[1];
aData[0] = -0.005;
```

won't really work, because aData[0] gets rounded to 0.
How to do it properly?

Comment: C doesn't have any support for half, you'll have to implement your own conversion from float

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a float to a half type and the other way around in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76799117/how-to-convert-a-float-to-a-half-type-and-the-other-way-around-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the GPU side, in OpenCL C, you treat the numbers as `half`, that part is correct. OpenCL C supports the `half` data type and arithmetic with it. It's better to use the `half2` vector type though, as only then you get the 2x FP16 arithmetic throughput of GPUs.

On the CPU side, you treat the numbers as `unsigned short` (this is what `cl_half` is under the hood), as they are only 16 bits in size and there is no `half` data type in C/C++. You can't just write 32-bit FP32 literals like `-0.005f` into there, as they will get casted to 16-bit integer. You need [proper `float` <-> `half` conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047308/9178992). Then, to write numbers:

```c
typedef unsigned short ushort;
ushort aData[1];
aData[0] = float_to_half(-0.005f);
```

And to read the data again:

```c
float result = half_to_float(aData[0]);
```

Note that on the CPU, arithmetic with the `ushort`/`cl_half` is not supported, and you always have to first convert the numbers to `float`.